# How do I make a "sticky menu" go back to it original class as I scroll back up?

Tags: javascript, header, scroll, nav, sticky

I am fairly new to javascript and I am trying to make a second sticky menu on my site. I have the second nav change its class as you scroll down which seems to work fine. However, I want it to go back to its original class once you scroll back up. Any help? The code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$(window).scroll(function () { 
        if (window.scrollY > 200)
        {
      $("#top-bar").removeClass("nav-main").addClass("navbar-inner").addClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
    }

    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something along the lines of an else to restore the original classes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$(window).scroll(function () { 
        if (window.scrollY > 200) {
           $("#top-bar").removeClass("nav-main").addClass("navbar-inner").addClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
        } else {
           $("#top-bar").addClass("nav-main").removeClass("navbar-inner").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It does restore the original class, however it keeps some parts of the other other class like background color, etc. I checked the code and as I scroll up the new added class and original one go into the class="" tag together. @easement

Comment: I left a space inside ("") tag its now fixed and it works! Thanks! @easement